# Mount and boot from a disk image (img/vhd) from grub2

Tags: linux, shell, mount, grub

I am looking for a way to mount an img file (Batocera to be precise) in grub2 and boot from it. It's located in an ntfs formatted partition. I was able to use the `loopback` command to `ls` into the image and initiate the boot process only to be greeted with "can't open blockdev" error message. As pointed out in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/412028/booting-an-ext4-image-file-from-grub2?newreg=2bccc7ed08af4ebc92836e0293df3d7c) thread, it's an obvious result given the fact that the image didn't get mounted.

**Things I would like to know**

Here are some questions which I would like to be answered, preferably with supporting resources for further reading, so that I can understand things better.

1. Can kpartx, losetup and loop mounting be used to mount the image pre-boot (when in grub2), so that the mounted media can be used as a boot device?
2. Is it possible to mount the image from grub shell using the built in commands? If so, how?
3. From similar previous posts, I learnt that an accompanying shell/bash script can be used to mount the image. Where does the script execute? In grub shell?
4. How do I execute the script? Should the script be run by adding a new grub menu entry or does it need to be added as a kernel parameter?
5. In the script, how do I specify the path to the image? Should I just use the grub shell format, ie., `(hd1, gpt3)/path/to/image.vhd`?

Disk information obtained using
`sudo parted /media/Boot/Batocera.vhd UNIT b print`

```
Number  Start     End       Size     File system  Name                Flags  

1      2048s     3145727s  3143680s  fat32        Basic data partition  msftdata  
2      3145728s  5281791s  2136064s  ext4         Basic data partition  msftdata
```

**Things I've tried**

I was able to successfully mount the image from ubuntu desktop using the below methods.

**losetup**

```
sudo losetup -Pf /media/Boot/Batocera.vhd
```

**kpartx**

```
$ sudo kpartx -av /media/Boot/Batocera.vhd    
add map loop18p1 (252:2): 0 3082240 linear /dev/loop0 2048    
add map loop18p2 (252:3): 0 17887232 linear /dev/loop0 3084288
```

**Mount and loop**

```
sudo mount /media/Boot/Batocera.vhd /mnt/boot_root \
-o loop,offset=2097152
```

But when I tried to run the following script during the boot process, nothing seems to happen.

```
#!/bin/sh

modprobe loop
modprobe vfat
modprobe ext4

mkdir /boot_root
mkdir /SHARE
mount -o loop,offset=1048576B -t vfat /media/Boot/Batocera.vhd /boot_root
mount -o loop,offset=1610612736B -t ext4 /media/Boot/Batocera.vhd /SHARE
```

GRUB2 Menuentry

```
menuentry "Batocera" {
    insmod ntfs
    insmod linux
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod part_msdos
    loopback loop (hd1,gpt4)/Boot/Distros/Batocera.vhd
    linux (loop,1)/boot/linux run_script=(hd1,gpt4)/Boot/Scripts/Mount_Partitions_2.sh root=/boot_root label=RECALBOX console=tty3
    initrd (loop,1)/boot/initrd.gz
}
```

**Limitations**

If at all possible, I would like to avoid any Kernel modifications / initramfs alterations as it ensures re-usability with future updates.

**Threads referred**

[Booting an EXT4 image file from GRUB2](https://superuser.com/questions/412028/booting-an-ext4-image-file-from-grub2?newreg=2bccc7ed08af4ebc92836e0293df3d7c)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/69363/mount-single-partition-from-image-of-entire-disk-device

Thanks for the help.

Comment: you must run the script from initramfs. use variables. you can make your script more generic with dynamic variables https://stackoverflow.com/a/55559199