# How can I boot a live system iso on a partition of an USB drive

Tags: linux, windows, boot, partitioning, grub

I am a linux and windows user, and I'm going to build up a USB drive(`/dev/sda`, got 3 partition already) which contains a windows PE and a linux livecd. I have got two iso files, and I'm trying a new way: `dd` them into two partitions:

```bash
sudo dd if=kali-live.iso of=/dev/sda2
sudo dd if=winPE.iso of=/dev/sda3
```

and I have just installed grub2 on my USB drive by following the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Multiboot_USB_drive):

```bash
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/mobile
sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --removable --boot-directory=/mnt/mobile/boot --efi-directory=/mnt/mobile
```

I'm showing what my USB drive like in GParted:

[my USB drive like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVVon.png)

and then, how should I config the file `/mnt/mobile/boot/grub/grub.cfg` to boot them? I have not got any idea from the web, including that arch wiki page.

*For each or the iso files, if I just do: dd if=xxx.iso of=/dev/sda and it will normally boot.*

**Note** this is **not** what I am asking:

- make a filesystem on /dev/sda2 and put a iso file into that filesystem. That's easy to boot.

I've not found amy page to solve my question.

I know someone have done that, but I do not know how to contact with. I'm gonna to try that way, which means one ISO file allocating one partition.

> Please forgive me if wrong language expression occurs, because my native language is not English. I'll apologize if this question is not appropriate here and I'm just a freshman here.

Comment: Writing to the whole device works because each image contains structures expected by UEFI (legitimately or by a "hack", see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1527373/432690)). What you are trying to do is to add one more layer in a stack of filesystems. It's not that different from this question: [*Is this possible to boot an OS from some kind of a file?*](https://superuser.com/q/1806768/432690) My answer there explains what I mean by "a stack of filesystems". I really don't know if it's easier to do it the way you want, or by storing the isos as regular files in a "real" filesystem.

Comment: An humble suggestion: Don't reinvent the wheel, use Ventoy: https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html

Comment: I know how to use ventoy. I just want to try this way, for I know somebody realized thw way I described and I can't find how to reach thay. Anyway, the way I issued is not the same as ventoy. anyway, thank for your suggestion.